# ORA-14224 Deferred Segment Creation is not supported for this schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm trying to use deferred segment creation and not having any success.

My deferred_segment_creation parameter is set to TRUE, but new tables do not defer.  I've also tried explicitly stating SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED in my create table statement but receiving the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE3 (n1 number) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED TABLESPACE MYTBS
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14224: Deferred segment creation is not supported for this schema
```

Can anyone provide some guidance regarding what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, do not use SYS for such operations.

```
SQL> show parameter deferred

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
deferred_segment_creation            boolean     TRUE

SQL> conn bp/bp
Connected.

SQL> CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE3 (n1 number) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED;

Table created.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE3 (n1 number) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE3 (n1 number) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14224: Deferred segment creation is not supported for this schema
```

[Restrictions on Deferred Segment Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html)

> This clause is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - You cannot defer segment creation for the following types of tables: clustered tables, global temporary tables, session-specific temporary
>     tables, internal tables, external tables, and tables owned by SYS,
>     SYSTEM, PUBLIC, OUTLN, or XDB.
> - Deferred segment creation is not supported in dictionary-managed tablespaces.
> - Deferred segment creation is not supported in the SYSTEM tablespace.
> - Serializable transactions do not work with deferred segment creation. Trying to insert data into an empty table with no segment
>     created causes an error.